# Fluent query with Unix Timestamps with Vapor 4

Tags: swift, unix-timestamp, vapor, vapor-fluent

I am new to Vapor/Fluent. I have a model with two timestamp fields like this:

```
import Fluent
import Vapor

final class User: Model, Content {

    @Timestamp(key: "updated_at", on: .update, format: .unix)
    var modificationDate: Date?

    @Timestamp(key: "deleted_at", on: .delete, format: .unix)
    var deletionDate: Date?
}
```

I want to write a Fluent query for users based on these dates, i.e. get all users with `modificationDate` or `deletionDate` not `nil` and within a given time interval. Something like this:

```
func getUpdatedOrDeletedUsers(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) async throws -> [User] {
   let interval: Range<Date> = startDate..<endDate
   return try await User.query(on: request.db)
                        .withDeleted()
                        .filter((\.$modificationDate != nil && interval.contains(\.$modificationDate!)) || (\.$deletionDate != nil && interval.contains(\.$deletionDate!)))
                        .all()
}
```

Unfortunately, this kind of syntax does not seem to be allowed. After reading the [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/query/) I came up with this solution:

```
func getUpdatedOrDeletedUsers(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) async throws -> [User] {
   return try await User.query(on: request.db)
                        .withDeleted()
                        .group(.or) { group in
                           group.group(.and) { group in
                              group.filter(\.$modificationDate != nil)
                                   .filter(\.$modificationDate >= startDate)
                                   .filter(\.$modificationDate < endDate)
                           }
                           .group(.and) { group in
                              group.filter(\.$deletionDate != nil)
                                   .filter(\.$deletionDate >= startDate)
                                   .filter(\.$deletionDate < endDate)
                           }
                        }
                        .all()
}
```

But this does not seem very readable. I thought about making two separate queries, but I think that might have a negative impact on performance. Is this the right way to do it with Fluent? Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't see the use case for a deletion time field. If you delete a user from a database, the entry is no longer there. To get all users just `User.query(on: request.db).all()`

Comment: If you add a deletion time field, that activates so called soft deletion in Vapor. The data will still be there after it got deleted, but it won't show up in (regular) queries. You can then either choose to permanently delete or restore it. In my use case this is pretty useful.

Comment: I forgot to add ```.withDeleted()``` in the example. Without that it would not make much sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the best way (short of renaming a few of the `group` variables for clarity